# Monitoring with Graphite - whisper don't save metrics

Tags: linux, monitoring, graphite

I succesfully installed Graphite by this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-graphite-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

and when I run:

```
echo "test.count 4 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 127.0.0.1 2003
```

and run: `whisper-fetch /var/lib/graphite/whisper/test/count.wsp`

the value 4 appears to be saved

but when I  run the same command later from another computer and I change localhost to my ip address:

```
echo "test.count 4 `date +%s`" | nc -q0 192.168.88.65 2003
```

the value appears not to be saved in whisper after all.

But when I delete the directory:

> /var/lib/graphite/whisper/test

and run previous command again, so the test folder will be created but without saving the value there.

Does anybody know how can I send the metrics to whisper from another computer in the same network?

I know the port is open because nmap returns:

```
martin at martin-pc templates >>> nmap 192.168.88.65

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-09-01 18:25 CEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.88.65
Host is up (0.0033s latency).
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
2003/tcp open  finger
2004/tcp open  mailbox
3000/tcp open  ppp
7002/tcp open  afs3-prserver
```

I think that it will probably be something in config (maybe the security policy) but I don't know what exactly.

**UPDATE:**
I don't know why, but when I rebooted computer so now it is all working ..

Answer (score 0):

Graphite has no security policies for port 2003, if it's listening on port 2003 - it will accept metrics there.

Comment: I rebooted computer and now it is working.. tkanks for your response :)